# Determine whether a given string is XML or not

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

I am using an API that returns XML if it succeeds and returns an error string if it fails. I would like to find a robust way of determining if a string is XML or just a string. I'd like to know if there is something that already exists in the framework before I try to do it myself.

Comment: I'm not really looking for using a try catch, because I'm not wanting to determine if the XML is valid. I'm wanting to determine if it is XML. I know that this would work, but I would honestly rather roll my own using Regex or something. Thanks.

Comment: How would you define the difference between something "being XML" and something "being valid XML"? What, in your use case, would be a sufficient indicator that the given string is XML?

Comment: PS--the reason I'm asking this is that it takes roughly the same amount of work to write code that perfectly determines whether text is XML as it takes to write a parser. You can't do it with Regex, for example. As http://redsymbol.net/articles/svg-markup-chomsky/ says, "You cannot create a finite state machine that will correctly discriminate all possible XML (or SVG or XHTML) documents. However, every context-free language has subsets that are regular. Sometimes this is useful." So if you can define a set of criteria that's "good enough" then people can provide you with a better answer.

Comment: No. But I can do it to recognize the difference intended XML and a plane string. This is what I am trying to do. I'm sorry, maybe the try / catch method is the way to go. I'm was just raised under the school that rejects try /catch blocks for anything other than exceptional behavior. I can remember a time when such code would suffer extreme performance hits.  I just thought there might be something obscure in the framework that could identify XML code. Something like `XDocument.TryParse` would work.

Comment: I share your dislike for flow-by-exception, but I couldn't think of a better way unless you can specify what the difference between XML and a "plain string" would look like. I offered one suggestion already, but you are more familiar with the types of "plain strings" getting returned, and whether or not they're likely, e.g., to start and end with `<>` tags.

Answer (score 1):

try to parse, if throw exception is not xml

```
string unknow = "";
try
{
    return XElement.Parse(unknow);
}
catch (System.Xml.XmlException)
{
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Don't really like flow-by-exception.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to let `XDocument` try parsing the input. If the parse is successful, the input is valid XML; otherwise, it's not a valid XML.

```
Boolean ValidateXml(string xmlString) {
    try {
        return XDocument.Load(new StringReader(xmlString)) != null;
    } catch {
        return false;
    }
}
```

This is a relatively expensive way of validating XML. If you plan to use parsed XML later on, I would change this to `TryParse`, and use the output like this:

```
Boolean TryParseXml(string xmlString, out XDocument res) {
    try {
        res = XDocument.Load(new StringReader(xmlString));
        return true;
    } catch {
        res = null;
        return false;
    }
}
```

Here is how I would call this method:

```
XDocument doc;
if (TryParseXml(response, out doc)) {
    // Use doc here
} else {
     // Process the error message
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A robust--but slow--way would be to parse out the result (`XElement.Parse()`)and see if it throws an exception.

```
public bool IsValidXml(string candidate)
{
    try{
        XElement.Parse(candidate);
    } catch(XmlException) {return false;}
    return true;
}
```

A less robust, but much more quick way would be to check some basic assumptions, like whether the string  (after trimming whitespace) starts and ends with `<>` tags.

Comment: All three of you suggest the same thing. And it's flow by exception.

Comment: @Jordan: That's true, because we all assume you'd rather not write your own XML parser, and .NET doesn't provide a mechanism for validating an XML structure without throwing an exception when the structure is invalid. You'll note that I *did* suggest a simple way to guess at whether the response is XML--it just won't work if the you get a response that's plain-text which someone has inexplicably surrounded with `<>` tags. You could also try a hybrid approach, where you start by doing a simple check for `<>` tags, and then move on to try parsing it only if that check fails.

Comment: .NET 5.0 better have `XDocument.TryParse` for us Exception purists. I should request that.

Comment: @Jordan: Agreed. Of course, I wouldn't be surprised if they're throwing these exceptions from deep down inside of recursive functions and such. If they do add it, they probably won't rewrite the whole thing to avoid ever throwing exceptions--guess how they'll go about implementing it? ;-)

Comment: Yes, I was thinking that myself, but I won't KNOW about it. Any performance hits would be the framework's fault.